2 GPUS render way slower than 1
GPUS I have: 4090 and 1050ti
Blender version 4.2.2 LTS
Some scenes that can be rendered on 4090 no problem can't be rendered when both are enabled because it's out of gpu memory.
The scenes that it can render the render times with both active are worse than just with 4090 active.
Blender is set to use 4090 as primary in graphics settings
Nvidia control panel openGL render card set to 4090
Win default high performance device set to 4090
Is there no way to make this work and add some small bit of speed from the 1050ti or are they just way too far apart performance wise to work properly?

It's been awhile since I reviewed the info about rendering with multiple GPUs in SLI, but from what I recall you're almost always going to get worse/neglibly increased performance unless both GPUs are identical. This thread has some good info to look into.

SLI and NVlink is discontinued on rtx40xx series

After asking around I learned that in simple terms - in 2-x card setups you will get double-x times the performance of the weakest card. So in my case I'll get 2x 1050ti performance even tho I have 4090. You will also get the VRAM amount equal to 1x your weakest card. If you want extra performance use 2 systems - 1 with one card and the other with another one, link them and use clustering software to divide render between them.
If you want a single machine workstation - use 2 equal cards that have NVlink connecting them so you can take advantage of double VRAM.
Best consumer cards for this are 3090. Best enterprise - A6000 ada as of November 2024
EDIT: You can use different cards and not link them but as mentioned the performance will diminish bringing it down to [card count]*weakest card performance levels and no link will limit your VRAM to 1x weakest card's VRAM. Correct me if I'm wrong

You don't need to connect any GPUs in any way to use them both for rendering in Blender as far as I know. Where are you taking this information from? Have you tested? Can you link to information sources?

You don't need to but you won't pool memory if you don't. If you place 2x 4090 in your system you will only have 1x 4090 VRAM. You need cards that can utilize NVlink or SLI to pool memory and take advantage of both cards' VRAM

Where do you get this information from? Can you cite a source that specifically explains how SLI combines memory of GPUs? That's incorrect and misleading as far as I know. NVLink is different thing.

Where do you get the idea that Cycles supports NVLink as well?

See: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/nvlink-in-blender-and-workstation-advice/23603

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqMFq_2htM - demonstrates blender utilizing NVlink. Please explain how to pool memory correctly if I am wrong.
